# Force a custom home screen app and don't allow the default back

Tags: android, android-intent

I'd like to have kind of a parental control option on my kids' phone that would work like this: the only way to use the phone is by doing a certain (potentially boring) task. The goal would be to discourage frequent phone use. So if the phone is off or the screen is blank/idle and they turn it on they are presented with a lock screen that makes them do a couple of things and they can only access all other normal phone features once they did what they were asked to do.

Now prior to android 4.0 I would implement a lock screen application and I would be done. But with 4.0+ the home button press event can not be caught so the lock screen app will not work, they will simply hit the home button.

With 4.0+ I can still implement a full home screen app or launcher though and I can catch the home button press events. This all looks great but my kids can simply go to the menu where they can choose from all available launchers, they will see my custom launcher and the default one, and they can simply select the default one.

It looks now to me that what I'd like to accomplish is simply not possible with 4.0+. Is this really the case or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of implementing home or lock screen you can write an app that will draw on other apps UI so your kids will have to do those boring tasks regardless of whether they lock the phone or what launcher they are using.

In order to do so you will need to implement a service (so that your code will run in the background - as you won't have your own activity running). 
You can get reference to the window manager by calling Context.getSystemService:

`mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);`

once you have reference to the window manager, simply create your own view (inflate it from XML or create it in code) and add it to the window by `mWindowManger.addView(...)`

Comment: But this app needs to be launched by something/somebody and if the kids decide to never launch it then how would it work? And why can't they just press the home key to bypass it?

Comment: 1. Your app can listen to screen On/Off event using receivers and auto lunch it. 2. Even if the kid presses on home screen - he will still see your app's UI because it will draw it on top of everything else, including the launcher.

Comment: But what if an incoming call comes? Since that will trigger the screen On event the app will launch, which is not what I'd want. An incoming call should be allowed without my app interfering.

Comment: That's easy to solve - all you need to do is check the phone state after you get ScreenOn event and before you force your UI on top of everything. You can do that by checking on TelephonyManager or by using a broadcast receiver that will listen to PHONE_STATE. Don't forget that you will need extra permission but I don't think that will be an issue in your case.

Comment: Sounds good, just one more question: is there a way to make the app auto start if it gets killed? I'm sure the kids will figure out sooner or later that what gets in their way is an always running service that can just be stopped.